# Validate string for numbers, letters and white space with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to save in a string only numbers and letters and white spaces. I need to use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`. If I put the string in a IF clause, it will only be valid if it contains only numbers, letters and white spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(yourstring, @"^[\d \w \s]+$"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("passed");
}
```

Explanation:

`^`: designates the beginning of a string
`$`: designates the end of a string
`[...]` matches all caracters inside the parantheses
`\d`    matches digits
`\w`    matches letters
`\s`    matches spaces
`+`    means 1 or more occurences

Comment: Thanks man this is just what I need

Comment: And whats about if I need non-spaces?

Comment: you are welcome. Such a question has been asked here a lot. Next time you should google a little before asking. If you need non-spaces then you just remove that part which matches the spaces